# Dropbox wont auto start on W10 machine

Tags: boot, dropbox

Ive got dropbox running on W10 Pro.

The W10 machine has mutliple users and from time to time is switched off and restarted.

Ive noticed that when i log in as a user sometimes dropbox's sync app dosnt launch.

`dropbox > preferences > start dropbox on system startup` is enabled.

`task manager > startup > dropbox` is set.

Any ideas why it wouldn't be launching ?

[image: screenshot of dropbox preferences and startup preferences]

Comment: Try this : In Dropbox preferences, select the proxies button. Then select 'No Proxy' instead of  the default 'Auto-detect'. Then click "Apply" and Ok, then reset the program.

Comment: Thanks ill give that a try and let you know how i get on @harrymc

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the following registry key in a batch file:

> reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v Dropbox /t REG_SZ /d [PathToDropboxExe] /f

Simply create a batch file with that command in it, and run it. This should add the file to startup for all users. If you want it only to run for the current user, replace `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.